# spark-submit won't work anywhere in cmd

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, cmd, pyspark, environment-variables

I am trying to run spark-submit command from drive/folder where my python script and dataset is `H:\spark_material`. It just won't work !

But if I copy my python script into this folder `C:\spark\bin` then it works.

I believe it has something to do with environment variables. 
Here is my Path = `%JAVA_HOME%\bin; %SPARK_HOME%\bin`

Here are my variables: 
`HADOOP_HOME = C:\winutils`
`JAVA_HOME = C:\jdk`
`SPARK_HOME = C:\spark`

Java is properly installed as I have tried typing "java -version" anywhere in CMD and it works!!

Comment: _"It just won't work !"_ does **not** work here either. What's `H:\spark_material`?! How could we know what's inside and what's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comman)

Comment: @Ben I looked on your `PATH` and I could see the mistake: There is space left of `C:\spark\bin`. This is the reason why nothing in that directory is found because the folder path is invalid because of this leading space character. I also strongly recommend to move `C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common` and `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` after folder path for PowerShell. No application installer should register the application's folder path before the most important standard Windows paths, but many installers are bad coded.

Comment: Can we have a look at the python code that you are using? Is there anything that is using relative path may be an issue.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski 'H:\spark_material' is the location where my python script is saved.

Comment: @Mofi There is no space in the path, and also tried moving paths you suggest. Still won't work.

Comment: @AbhayDandekar I am just using sample code from apache spark website to test out the spark-submit command .. so the code is: 'text_file = spark.textFile("file:///H:/spark_material/test.py")
 
text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split())
    .map(lambda word: (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was/is mystery - I re-installed everything one by one on my machine except operating system and it was an issue with Python distribution in my opinion. When I reinstalled Canopy(enthought), spark-submit command started to work. I still don't know why it happened as even in my previous version of Canopy (Python) was working fine properly.

Thank you everyone for your response and contribution. Learnt a lot from you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Open your cmd and type path and check is apache spark path specify till bin folder
If not please fix your path

Comment: It's there....C:\>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\jdk\bin; C:\spark\bin

Comment: No issue in your path , sorry not sure if any changes in window server 2012